# Trigonometry $\tan \theta = \dfrac43$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

If $\tan \theta = \dfrac43$, find $\cos \theta$ and $\sin \theta$.

I have the answers, but I don't know what to do at all, is it going to be easy?

Comment: you have a triangle with 3 , 4 , 5.

Answer (score 6):

**Geometric Approach**

Make a (rough) sketch of a right triangle with one angle $\theta$. Then the opposite side and adjacent side are in the ratio $4:3$, as $\tan\theta = \dfrac{\text{Opposite side}}{\text{Adjacent side}}$. You can assume the sides to be exactly $4$ and $3$. Calculate the hypotenuse using Pythagorean theorem. Then calculate $\sin \theta$ and $\cos \theta$.

As 5xum points out, this is not very general. A more general approach is the algebraic one.

**Algebraic Approach**

$
\tan\theta = \dfrac{4}{3} \Rightarrow\\
\dfrac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta} = \dfrac{4}{3} \Rightarrow\\
\cos\theta = \dfrac{3}{4}\sin\theta
$

Now,
$
\cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta = 1 \Rightarrow\\
\dfrac{9}{16}\sin^2\theta + \sin^2\theta = 1 \Rightarrow\\
\sin^2\theta = \dfrac{16}{25} \Rightarrow\\
\sin\theta = \pm \dfrac{4}{5}
$

Then $\cos\theta = \dfrac{\sin\theta}{\tan\theta} = \pm\dfrac{3}{5}$ (with respective signs).

Thus
$$\boxed{
\begin{matrix}
\sin\theta = \dfrac{4}{5},\ \cos\theta = \dfrac{3}{5}\\
\text{or}\\
\sin\theta = -\dfrac{4}{5},\ \cos\theta = -\dfrac{3}{5}
\end{matrix}
}
$$

Comment: This approach does not deal with the possibility that $\theta$ may not be in $[0,\pi/2]$

Comment: @5xum Fixed, I think?

Comment: I agree. Just fix the last value of $\cos \theta$ to $-\frac35$.

Comment: Damn sign. Thanks, @5xum!

Answer (score 4):

Do you know that
$$1+\tan^2\theta=\frac1{\cos^2\theta}$$
and 
$$\sin\theta=\tan\theta\cos\theta$$

Answer (score 3):

I would try to visualize a right triangle. In other words draw a picture of a right triangle and label one of the angles $\theta$ and fill in the lengths of the sides that you know.

For this triangle we have:

```
 |\
4|  \
 |    \
 |_____ \ <- theta
   3
```

Now use the pythagorean theorem to find the final sides length and then finally calculate $\sin \theta, \cos \theta$.

EDIT: I've been corrected properly, you also need to consider a triangle with negative values on the legs, since $4/3=(-4)/(-3)$ i.e.

```
  |\
-4|  \
  |    \
  |_____ \ <- theta
    -3
```

and then go through the process as above to find the second set of possible values for $\sin \theta, \cos \theta$.

I'm going to go for a more visual approach to this, ignoring the triangle above. Consider a 2D cartesian graph, let's try to draw the possible triangles that the above condition represents. In order for $\tan \theta = \frac{4}{3}$ we either have a triangle in the first or third quadrant. Drawing these two triangles we either get

```
               /|
              / |
             /  |
            /   |
           /    | 4
          /     |
theta -> /______|
            3
```

or

```
         -3
   -------------- <- theta
   |            /
   |           /
-4 |          /
   |         /
   |        /
   |       /
   |      /
   |     /
   |    /
   |   /
   |  /
   | /
   |/
```

Now we can use the pythagorean theorem (taking the hypotenuse as positive since the slope here is clearly positive) to find the last sides of the triangles and from there find $\sin \theta, \cos \theta$.

Comment: This approach does not deal with the possibility that $\theta$ may not be in $[0,\pi/2]$

Comment: @5xum for this problem it works, and it appears the OP wants help with problems similar to this one (i.e. where a geometrical approach is acceptable) hence I posted the solution I did (where $\theta \in (0,\pi/2)$.

Comment: I don't think it does work for this problem, as the solution $\cos \theta = -\frac35 \sin\theta = -\frac45$ cannot be found like this.

Comment: @5xum are you saying because there is a possibility of having negative values for the cosine and sine? If so then you can be more precise with the geometric view and take the legs of the triangles to have both negative values as well and find the possible solutions from there as well.

Comment: @5xum that's a fair point, I edited my post accordingly.

Comment: The cosine and sine functions are more than just their geometric interpretations. It is a fact that $\cos \frac{5\pi}{4} = -\frac{\sqrt2}{2}$, and this has little to do with the original high school interpretations of the cosine function. I don't have to be precise with the geometric view, I discarded it.

Comment: Also, I don't think your second picture is very good, as negative lengths for triangle sides are not a good way to imagine negative values of the cosine and sine function. After all, what in your second picture is the value of the hypotenuse? $-5$ or $5$, and what is your justification for taking any of them?

Comment: @5xum It's clear (at least to me) that the OP is looking for my explanation. This is because a triangle which is described by his statement is a pythagorean triple. As for the second picture, it can be either (since square roots are unique). Taking the different possibilities in the hypontenuse will give us all the possible values for $\cos \theta, \sin \theta$.

Comment: @5xum the basic geormetric approach to describing angles is by drawing them on a graph and going from there. With this in mind *negative* sides have a very significant meaning (their orientation). With that said, if you want to demean me because I disagree with your view that geometry can't solve a simple trigonometric problem, that doesn't seem fair. If you agree the OP is looking for an answer like mine then my answer should be fine, if not then you're disregarding everything I'm saying.

Comment: I am not demeaning you. I do, however, think that if a high school student was to look at your answer, he would actually be more confuzed after reading it than before (even if he thought he understood more, he would in fact not). I have nothing against you, personally, but I do think that this answer is bad. And I am not saying that "geometry can't solve a simple trigonometric problem", I am saying that problems involving trigonometric functions are not only geometric, but also algebraic (as m. Vinays answer shows).

Comment: @5xum "significant lack of mathematical knowledge" seems to be quite demeaning to me... nonetheless, that's *your* opinion. I remember as a high school student I understood this argument. So again I see no problem with the geometric approach (that is using a graph and having an orientation to the triangle). You could also say that problems involving trigonometric functions actually deal with differential equations, and work from there, but again I don't think that's the correct answer to *this* question.

Comment: I am sorry for the comment that insulted you, it was poorly worded. It is a poorly translated figure of speech from my own language. What I wanted to say is what I explained in the next comment. Anyway, I think we can safely say we agree to disagree on this topic. I still think your answer is wrong and that negative values of triangle lengths cause only confusion. Obviously, you disagree, but I suggest we leave it at that.

Comment: @5xum thank you, I apologize for causing such a ruckus, and I agree on leaving it at what it is.

Answer (score 3):

You use $$\sec^2 a=1+\tan^2 a$$ so you get value of $\sec a$, since $\cos a$ is reciprocal of $\sec a$, you can find $\cos a$. The rest is easy.

Comment: @Fantini, thanks for your apt edit.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\tan\theta = \frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}$, you know that $$\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta} = \frac{4}{3}.$$

Now, if we say that $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$ are two variables, that means you have one equation for the two variables. Do you know of any other equation in which the two variables appear? (*Hint*: you do).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :**
$$
\tan\theta=\frac yx=\frac43
$$
then
$$
\sin\theta=\frac y{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}
$$
and
$$
\cos\theta=\frac x{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}.
$$

Comment: These formulae annoy me, because they are the kind of formulae that students memorise before sitting an exam. They memorise these formulae as a substitution for understanding what is going on, or for getting to know one of the "standard" formula (e.g. $1+\tan^2\theta=\sec^2\theta$).